How to make the enumerate counter start at a chosen number
The below code works nicely if I go from Step 1,2,3... but how do I change the counter to be started with Step 3, not Step 1?
\begin{enumerate}[{Step~}1:]
    \item   
    \item    
\end{enumerate} 


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

You can increase the counter like this:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[{Step~}1:]
\addtocounter{enumi}{2}
\item test
\item test
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


The same also works in beamer, you just don't have to load the enumerate package:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}[{Step~}1:]
\addtocounter{enumi}{2}
\item test
\item test
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


@samcarter_is_at_topanswer.xyz It work. Thank you so much!
